# How to get (logical) screen size from a shell script?

Tags: macos, bash, screen, resolution, automation

Using `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`, I can retrieve the size of a Mac's display in pixels.
However, the command

```
tell application "System Events" to get the size of every window of every process
```

(which I execute from my bash script using `osascript`) apparently does NOT return window sizes in pixels. It seems to be some other units. According to my experiments, on my MacBook Pro Retina, for instance, a fullscreen app (e.g., Keynote presentation) has a window size of 1680 x 1050.

So, the question is: how can I determine the screen size of a Mac from my bash script in the same units like the `tell application ...` uses?
Or, how can I determine the factor by which I have to convert pixels into those other units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen size with this command

```
fullscreen_size=$( osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to get bounds of window of desktop' )
```

in the same units as `tell application "System Events" ...`.

Comment: I'm running High Sierra on my old iMac and the Applescript line "tell application "Finder" to get bounds of window of desktop" doesn't work. Was this command changed in Catalina? When I run this single line in the Script Editor I get an error message that says "Can’t get bounds of window of desktop."

Comment: Sorry, couldn't tell, since i never tried it on older versions of macOS and don't have access to an older macOS